# Google API HTTP exception handling doesn't work (python)

Tags: python, exception, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I am trying to catch HTTP errors. I used following options:
1) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError
2) google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound

Neither of these options work for me. Any ideas why? Thank you!

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
#from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID for this request.
project = 'aweqwfnwrueifubwerfbiu'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

try:
    request = service.firewalls().list(project=project)
except errors.HttpError:
    pprint('Error!')

while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()

    for firewall in response['items']:
        # TODO: Change code below to process each `firewall` resource:
        pprint(firewall)

    request = service.firewalls().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = request.execute()
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/aweqwfnwrueifubwerfbiu/global/firewalls?alt=json returned "The resource 'projects/aweqwfnwrueifubwerfbiu' was not found">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for handling the error

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
```

However, the error doesn't appear to be raising where your exception catch is. It's here

```
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
```

Not here

```
try:
    request = service.firewalls().list(project=project)
except errors.HttpError:
    pprint('Error!')
```

So try changing it to this

```
while request is not None:
    try:
        response = request.execute()
    except errors.HttpError:
        pprint('Error!')
```